# Equipartition theorem - concerning the square dependence of energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

So the equipartition theorem states that if the energy dependence is square
($\langle\,E\,\rangle= as^2$ + ...(something not dependent on $s$))
then each variable (degree of freedom) contributes exactly $\frac{1}{2}kT$ to the internal energy.
My question is. What are some examples of energy not having a square dependence.
I'm asking this because a lot of literature doesn't explicitly state the "square dependence", they just say, in a nutshell, degree of freedom = $(1/2) kT$, whereas the square dependence is now emphasized.

Comment: Gravitational potential energy would be a good example.

Comment: The classic example is in quantum systems, where the energy can only take a discrete set of values. This results in degrees of freedom "freezing out" when $k_BT$ is less than the separation of the energy levels

Comment: Thanks, never thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ultra relativistic gas has a linear energy dependence, so that each degree of freedom gets a full $kT$, and not $\frac 1 2 kT$.